# Possible causes of a Python ValueError

Tags: python, debugging, error-handling

I realize I don't provide a whole lot of details there, but that's just the nature of this beast.

Lately, when participating in various coding puzzles and using Python, I've found that code I use to solve quite a lot of test data does not pass all tests on the server. Namely, I am told the code raises a ValueError.

Now, these challenges don't tell me anything more specific than this for a reason, and I can't share the code I'm writing as that would be against both the spirit of said challenges, and against the rules.

But for people more experienced with Python than I, what sort of heuristics can I employ when I try and scan through my code for potential ValueError causing bugs?

The official Python documentation only has this to say:

```
exception ValueError
Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has
the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not
described by a more precise exception such as IndexError.
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, value errors occur, when you try to convert a string to a number, which isn't a number. For example:

```
>>> int("13a")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '13a'
```

Comment: Hmmm, in the particular problem I'm looking at right now does not have non-integers in the input. But I'm sure that sort of problem could plague me somewhere else. I'll keep it in mind. Thanks.